# Gradle : How to translate some groovy code to kotlin

Tags: gradle, kotlin, groovy, gradle-kotlin-dsl

The groovy code below is working fine in a script *build.gradle* :

```
task sourcesJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: classes) {
    from sourceSets.main.allSource
    classifier = 'sources'
}

artifacts {
    archives sourcesJar
}
```

I can't succeed in translating its syntax to kotlin *build.gradle.kts*. Could someone give me the correct translation ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Gradle 6, then this is trivial with the `java` plugin:

```
plugins {
    java
}

java {
    withSourcesJar()
}
```

If you are on an older version of Gradle or unable to upgrade, then you'll need to define the task as you have above:

```
plugins {
    java
}

val sourcesjar by tasks.registering(Jar::class) {
    from(sourceSets[SourceSet.MAIN_SOURCE_SET_NAME].allSource)
    // Use archiveClassifier on Gradle 5.1+ otherwise use classifier
    archiveClassifier.set("sources")
}

artifacts {
    archives(sourcesjar.get())
}
```

Comment: My code is not java but kotlin. Sorry I forgot to specify it.

Comment: I use gradle 6.1.1. The gradle build task gives no error but provides no class, makin the run fail. I do not know how to tell gradle to compile the kotlin code from the usual src/main/kotlin directory.

Comment: This was missing to make gradle compile the code

```plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "${extra["kotlinVersion"]}"
}```